# WordPress Functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a WordPress "framework" for myself. Looking at the [functions.php file](http://d.pr/f/kqw8) file, is there redundant or bad code that could be changed or some code that could be good to add?

The functions.php should be a file that I could use in every web project with little or no change.

Is this code good to put in the functions.php file?

Code (block scrollable):

```
/*
 * Default theme setup
 */
function beeFramework_setup() {

    // This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style,
    // specifically font, colors, icons, and column width.
    add_editor_style( array( 'css/editor-style.css', 'fonts/genericons.css' ) );

    // Adds RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // Switches default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
    // to output valid HTML5.
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list' ) );


    // This theme supports all available post formats by default.
    // See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'aside', 'audio', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video'
    ) );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    //register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Navigation Menu', 'twentythirteen' ) );

    // This theme uses its own gallery styles.
    add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'beeFramework_setup' );

/*
 * Disable WordPress Update Notifications For All But Administrator
*/
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_core_updates' );
    function remove_core_updates()
    {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', '__return_null' );
    add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', '__return_null' );
}


if ( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
}


/*
 * Load Styles and Scrips Front end
*/
function twentythirteen_scripts_styles() {

    // Add Genericons font, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/genericons.css', array(), '2.09' );

    // Loads our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentythirteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '2013-07-18' );

    // Loads the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentythirteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentythirteen-style' ), '2013-07-18' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentythirteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentythirteen_scripts_styles' );


/*
 * Nice Title Text
*/
function bee_freame_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentythirteen' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'bee_freame_wp_title', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Prints HTML with meta information for current post: categories, tags, permalink, author, and date.
*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'twentythirteen_entry_meta' ) ) :
function twentythirteen_entry_meta() {
    if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() )
        echo '<span class="featured-post">' . __( 'Sticky', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>';

    if ( ! has_post_format( 'link' ) && 'post' == get_post_type() )
        twentythirteen_entry_date();

    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentythirteen' ) );
    if ( $categories_list ) {
        echo '<span class="categories-links">' . $categories_list . '</span>';
    }

    // Translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma.
    $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentythirteen' ) );
    if ( $tag_list ) {
        echo '<span class="tags-links">' . $tag_list . '</span>';
    }

    // Post author
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
        printf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="author">%3$s</a></span>',
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
            esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentythirteen' ), get_the_author() ) ),
            get_the_author()
        );
    }
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentythirteen_entry_date' ) ) :
/**
 * Prints HTML with date information for current post.
 *
 * Create your own twentythirteen_entry_date() to override in a child theme.
 *
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 *
 * @param boolean $echo Whether to echo the date. Default true.
 * @return string The HTML-formatted post date.
 */
function twentythirteen_entry_date( $echo = true ) {
    if ( has_post_format( array( 'chat', 'status' ) ) )
        $format_prefix = _x( '%1$s on %2$s', '1: post format name. 2: date', 'twentythirteen' );
    else
        $format_prefix = '%2$s';

    $date = sprintf( '<span class="date"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a></span>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentythirteen' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( sprintf( $format_prefix, get_post_format_string( get_post_format() ), get_the_date() ) )
    );

    if ( $echo )
        echo $date;

    return $date;
}
endif;

/**
 * Returns the URL from the post.
 */
function twentythirteen_get_link_url() {
    $content = get_the_content();
    $has_url = get_url_in_content( $content );

    return ( $has_url ) ? $has_url : apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() );
}

/**
 * Add postMessage support for site title and description for the Customizer.
 */
function twentythirteen_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport         = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogdescription' )->transport  = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_textcolor' )->transport = 'postMessage';
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'twentythirteen_customize_register' );
```

Answer (score 4):

The code seems pretty solid. I'll make some small observations:

1. I'd remove `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_core_updates' );` and add a call to the function `remove_core_updates()` at the end of `beeFramework_setup()`.
2. The use of anonymous functions, `create_function`, prevents something like:

   ```
   # In your functions.php file
   add_action( 'init', 'remove_version_check', 2 );
   function remove_version_check() {
       remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );
   }

   # Later in a child theme or plugin
   remove_action( 'init', 'remove_version_check', 2 );
   ```
3. The filter `pre_option_update_core` could be simply:

   ```
   add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', '__return_null' );
   ```
4. Make sure you know the difference between [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) and [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) and use them accordingly.
5. Why would you check if Twenty Thirteen functions exists? Create good prefixes for your functions and drop the `function_exists` thing. I'd recommended using [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) instead of [pluggable functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions).
6. And, finally, speaking of hooks, provide some of them so people can modify the theme behavior from a child theme or plugin:

   ```
   # In your functions.php file
   $post_formats = array( 'aside', 'audio', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video' );
   add_theme_support( 'post-formats', apply_filters( 'my_framework_post_formats', $post_formats ) );

   # Later on a child theme or plugin we can reduce their number
   add_filter( 'my_framework_post_formats', 'my_new_post_formats' );
   function my_new_post_formats( $formats ) {
       return array( 'audio', 'gallery', 'image' );
   }
   ```